# Windows phones 7 GPS location

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I need to get my current location using GPS programmatically for windows phone 7. How do I do that?

Comment: what have you tried? google says a lot even the first link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225318/Simple-GPS-Locator-for-Windows-Phone-7

Comment: saw some codes on net and understood its concept

Comment: please then explain what you've tried and if it doesn't work show us some code so we can help with what's going wrong. For full articles on how to do it from scratch, i recommend more google :)

Comment: ok thnks :( i will do more rnd

Answer (score 0):

GeoCoordinateWatcher is the class you can use

sample on MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx